# is there any trouble in instantiating the same thread many times?

Tags: android

I have an app where I use a thread to read some information from the network and display it on the screen. I also have a button that on clicked refreshes the screen. Since I need to use the same thread to get and display such information and the threads cannot be restarted, I create a new instance of this thread every time this button is tapped. Is this a good practice, or will I use up too many memory resources due to so many threads created? It is also worth pointing out that the thread in turn creates new objects every time it is started, such as:

```
new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(app.socket
                        .getOutputStream())), true);

new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(app.socket.getInputStream()));
```

that are never deleted, not sure if they are automatically deleted when the thread stops running but i guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about using too much resources than you can queue up your threads by using only one instance of a Handler. Use Handler.post(new runnable())...This will queue your threads and will ensure that your objects get GCed correctly.